# How to graphically print a generic tree?

Tags: tree, graphviz

I have to be able to represent a generic tree with Graphviz. 
Each node of the tree is a Node object made ​​in this way:

```
private static int counter = 0;
private String text = "node";
private Step[] step;
private List<Node> children;
private Node parent = null;
```

Step is an object looks like this:

```
private char char;
private char cipherChar;
```

The class that represents the tree (Tree class) contains these fields and methods:

```
private Node root;
private Node last;
private Node parent;
private String name;
private String message;

public void print(String indent) {
    ArrayList<Node> tree = new ArrayList<Node>();
    tree = getPreOrderTraversal();
    for(int i = 0; i < tree.size(); i++) {
        tree.get(i).printSoluzione();
    }
}

private String printGraphviz() throws IOException {
    String g = new String("");
    g = g.concat("digraph G {\n");
    if(root == null) 
        g = g.concat("    " + "Empty tree.");
    else {
        ArrayList<Node> nodi = new ArrayList<Node>();
        nodi = getPreOrderTraversal();
        for(int i = 0; i < nodi.size(); i++) {
            if(nodi.get(i).getParent() != null) {
                g = g.concat("\t\"" + nodi.get(i).getParent().getText() + "\" -> \"" + nodi.get(i).getText() + "\"\n");
            }
        }
    }
    g = g.concat("}");
    return g;
}

public void toString(String fileDot){
    try {
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileDot); 
        PrintStream Output = new PrintStream(file);
        Output.print(this.printGraphviz()); 
        Output.close(); 
        File f = new File(fileDot); 
        String arg1 = f.getAbsolutePath(); 
        String arg2 = arg1 + ".png"; 
        String[] c = {"dot", "-Tpng", arg1, "-o", arg2};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(c); 
        int err = p.waitFor(); 
    }
    catch(IOException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e2) {
        System.out.println(e2);
    }
}
```

With this code, when I call the function `print("")` it generates a picture like this: 
http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/5a9c/km8jkb6wm9qn4fyfg.jpg?size_id=4

But I wish that was present within each node of the array Step, then an image like this: 
http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/4c2e/8267kphkp0824o3fg.jpg?size_id=5

In other words, I would like each node to be shown all the steps and not the name of the node.
How can I change the method `printGraphviz()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code that writes the node names into the string `g` so I can't say exactly how to write the revised code. However, you'll need to use the `label` attribute of the nodes so that you end up with the string `g` including lines that look like:

```
node0 [label="A=b"]
node1 [label="A=b\nD=f"]
```

... etc. See the `label` entry in [Node, Edge and Graph Attributes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3alabel) in the GraphViz documentation for more information.